# Does the inverse square law apply to all lights, including light within a lens?

Tags: lens, optics

In *The Cine Lens Manual* by Jay Holben and Christopher Probst pp.46, it is mentioned that the light loses brightness/intensity even within the lens.

This part is discussed right after the inverse square law, and they did not specify what rule the loss abides by. Since light within the lens does not travel as simply as light from a candle, this makes me wonder (not considering the obvious physical loss after passing through a glass element):

Is the loss of brightness/intensity inside the lens due to the inverse square law? Or is it due to scattering and (as they mentioned) the conservation of energy? Or a combination of both?

Comment: might be easier to re-imagine it as sound, which also abides ISL; in that case the lens acts like a pipe for the sound.

Answer (score 4):

Light from a normal point source travels omnidirectionally, so a given number of photons(1) traveling outward from a light source must illuminate a larger sphere the further you get from the source.

One way to intuit the law of inverse squares is to think about putting a postage stamp on a basketball, then putting the same postage stamp on a beach ball with double the radius. A fixed area on the surface of the sphere constitutes an ever decreasing percentage of the sphere.

> ##### Math Nerd Break
>
> Because the formula for the surface area of the sphere is `4πr²` the
> portion of the sphere covered by a fixed area n would be `n/4πr²`. We
> can further simplify this by setting n to `4π` and we get `1 * 1/r²`
> (the inverse square of the radius). If we set n to `2π` we get `1/2 * 1/r²`. This works no matter what size n is. And since everything else
> is constant, we can simplify it to for any given area, if you double r
> you get `1/r²` the light.

This, of course, only works for omnidirectional point (or near point) sources of light.

This gets muddied up in lenses. (Let us assume for the moment we *could* design a lens with no reflection or refraction and perfect transmission.) Once the light hits the front element, it ceases to travel along its original trajectory. Inside the lens it is getting bent and redirected do it can be focused down to a point again.

Alan's excellent answer is in reference to the entire image area, but let us consider a point source that the law of inverse squares would apply to (that being the reflected light of of any given point on your subject).

This diagram shows 3 point sources of light going through a hypothetical perfect single lens system and focusing onto the image plane. Once the light from a given point hits the surface of the lens, it stops "spreading" and starts to converge, so the law of inverse squares no longer applies.

[image: Points]

A more distant point will supply a smaller percentage of its light to the element, but it will also have more neighboring points focusing down onto the same sensel or grain, so there is very little effective difference. This is why you don't need to adjust your settings if the distance to your subject doubles (and your focal length does not).

As Alan (very correctly) points out, taking a relatively smaller total image area does reduce the amount of light available, hence telephoto lenses having larger front elements to capture a larger area of the light cast off the subject. This is also why "fixed aperture"(2) telephoto lenses are built to relatively adjust(3) how much light they are blocking with the aperture so they can maintain a constant exposure value across all the points in the image. "Normal" zoom lenses do not perform the complex ballet of element movement to achieve this, but it is the trade off of weight, cost, and complexity that is the cause of the lost of light as you zoom on these lenses, not the law of inverse squares due to the distance traveled within the lens.

So I think it is safe to say that no, the law of inverse squares is not at play inside a lens in any appreciable way. All the math still checks out if you think of it from the perspective of the imagable area of point sources passing through the lens (the behavior of the image is a cumulative reflection "inside" the lens of the actual individual point sources outside the lens). But no, the loss inside the lens is not from the distance the light travels.

#### tl;dr

Once a point source of light hits the front element, you can effectively ignore the law of inverse squares because the light is no longer diverging from the source, but rather converging onto the image plane.

1. or if you prefer, the intensity of the waves
2. most (if not all) telephoto lenses maintain a fixed physical aperture as they zoom, so this is a bit of a misnomer, "fixed f-number" would be more accurate
3. by manipulating the shape of the image cone passing through the physically fixed aperture opening, not by adjusting the size of the aperture opening

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148263/discussion-on-answer-by-lightbender-does-the-inverse-square-law-apply-to-all-lig); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3):

The law of the inverse square tells us that light intensity falls off 4x with each doubling of distance. In other words, if you are reading a book by the light of a single lightbulb 1 foot away from the book, move back so the book is 2 feet away from the bulb, the light playing on the book is ¼ as bright. This law strictly pertains to point-sources. If the source is a bank of fluorescent bulbs, called a “broad” in photo lingo, the fall-off is practically negligible.

As to light as it traverses the lens: Glass is not perfectly transparent, so the light dims a tiny bit as it passes through the glass. Generally, the loss is negatable. However, the glass lens has polished surfaces which reflects away about 2% on entry. This happens at each junction. A modern camera lens has multiple glass elements, the loss mounts with each interface. A loss of 50% is not uncommon. Loss by reflection results in stray light bouncing about. Some will bathe the projected image during the exposure. This action induces flair that robs the image of some of its contrast.  This is devastating to the final image as it also induces ghost images.

Early lens maker Tayler in London noted that older lenes seemed to pass more light than new ones of the same design. He figured out that air pollution had “bloomed” (tarnished) these older lenses (coal burning fumes). A thin coat of gunk cut the light loss, He patented the coating of lenses to mitigate loss by reflection. This works based on the thickness of the coat. Light waves can be canceled or reinforced by a thin film overcoat.

The loss in image brilliance of the projected image falls off following the law of the inverse square.  Double the focal length, the light must travel 2x further to reach the imaging chip or film.  This elongated projection distance doubles the size of projected images. A 2x magnification quadruple's' the surface area thus the light must now play or 4x more area. The light loss is 4x for every doubling of the focal length.

The light loss due to focal length is mitigated by increasing the working diameter of the lens. The f-number system does this trick. Any lens set to the same f-number as another lens delivers the same image brightness.

Loss as light traverses the lens is due to its imperfect transparency.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is empirical. I will not try to make a mathematical one. This is only a series of statements.

1. In general, the inverse square law applies to a point light.
2. Every big diffusive light at some distance will behave as a point light.
3. But also, every point of the diffuse light also behaves as a point light, so it also applies.
4. But some light, in theory, does not behave like that, mainly parabolic ones, where, in perfect conditions, the light rays do not spread at the same rate, because they are theoretically parallel, not divergent. They will diverge but not at the same rate, so (I think) the fall-off is less noticeable at close range. Here it is a video on which a parabolic light was constructed, but as it is using a parabolic antenna it is much more efficient than a parabolic softbox, and you can see that the fall-off is almost not noticeable. https://youtu.be/6bqBsHSwPgw?si=Da3vOb-Ha8Avy7VF (I have not finished mine to experiment)
5. So, inside a lens, you have sections that do not behave like a point light, in fact overall, a lens is meant to focus the light. So there will be zones where in fact the light is not divergent but, yes the following word has a lot of meaning, focusing. Beyond the focusing point, they will diverge according to the law.